# How can i create a model with self referencing EFCore

Tags: c#, code-first, ef-fluent-api, self-reference, ef-core-2.1

i create an wpf app and i create the database with entityFrameworkCore but i can't create an model with self referencing. 
I try all thats options

My model

```
public class Tag
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TagID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int TagLevel { get; set; }      
        public int? TagMotherID { get; set; }

        public virtual Tag TagMother { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> ListOfTagsChild { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ArchiveTag> ListOfArchive { get; set; }
}
```

and in OnModelCreating method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
                .HasOne(entity => entity.TagMother)
                .WithMany(entity => entity.ListOfTagsChild)
                .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.TagMotherID);
```

A tag can have one or zero parent but he can have many childs

with this i have this error

> SqlException: The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_Tags_Tags_TagMotherID". The conflict occurred in database "EFCoreTest", table "dbo.Tags", column 'TagID'.

Answer (score 1):

Please try changing OnModelCreating to

```
 .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.TagMotherID);
```

Comment: It is already there in my code it just was an error by me but doesn't work  =/